# In a given place in an aggregate initialization list, are values passed into previous places safe to read from the corresponding members?

Tags: c++, aggregate-initialization

```
struct
{
    int a,b;
} s = {5, s.a+1};
```

According to the standard, is it safe to read "s.a" in the above example, so that s is initialized to a=5 and b=6?  If so, do most compilers obey this rule?

(The above compiles in VC10.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because aggregate member initialization is sequenced.

**[dcl.init.aggr]**/2 has:

> When an aggregate is initialized by an *initializer list*, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list
>   are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order. Each
>   member is copy-initialized from the corresponding *initializer-clause*.

**[dcl.init.list]**/4 has:

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the *initializer-clauses*, including any that result from pack
>   expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and
>   side effect associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*.

The copy-initialization of an aggregate member is certainly a side effect (**[intro.execution]**/12), and must be "associated with" the corresponding *initializer-clause*, because that is its *full-expression* (since an *initializer-list* is not an expression).

Every up-to-date compiler I have tried (MSVC, Clang, g++) compiles this correctly. It may be possible that some older compilers get it wrong (older versions of g++ were known for getting the sequencing of aggregate initializers wrong).

Comment: Thanks!  Just double-checking -- are you using latest version of the spec?  I know C++11 introduced some new behavior regarding initializer syntax.

Comment: @KeithRussell yes, this is C++11 (and C++14). C++03 was underspecified in this regard.